Are multiple comments with "Worked on XYZ OS" useful?
It is reasonably common to see posts (such as this answer) with multiple short comments such as:

Worked on Windows 8 too
Great !! Worked with windows 10 also.
Worked on Manjaro
Worked on Raspberry Pi OS.
Worked on Windows 11.
Worked on Linux AWS box.

I have also noticed posts with similar comments but referring to different versions of Internet Explorer (or other browsers) or different versions of specific operating systems (i.e. various versions of Ubuntu).
On the one hand, this appears to be useful information, however on the other hand for many situations this just seems to be extra noise.
Are there any guidelines or advice what to do with these types of comments?

Seems like they are appropriate for a No Longer Needed (NLN) flag to me. If the users want to "celebrate" the answer worked, they have an upvote button they can press.

The thing that strikes me here is why would the OS even matter?! This is a Bash command that they use. Presumably in Git Bash or WSL or whatever else runs on Windows and executes Bash commands. Surely the host OS is irrelevant, if it doesn't work, it'd be related to the emulation/translation layer used. So it can both work and not work on the same OS. Because it's not the OS that dictates this. There is also a special case for updates which might break preciously working stuff but...surely "Works in Windows 8" cannot be generally true then.

The browser comments are probably more prudent though, although they will age away and especially ones related to Internet Explorer already have of course. Back in the day finding CSS and/or Javascript that would work on all browsers your employer forced you to support was a right pain in the neck. Far less so today fortunately. Such comments can have temporary value. Operating systems though... less so.

Why is this closed? It worked in Quora!

@user4581301 A) that question makes no sense, Stack Overflow and Quora are nothing alike so it is fully expected that outcomes are different. And B) It is not illegal to ask a question in several sites, if your real goal was to underhandedly call it out.

Beg to differ . The comment makes perfect sense. The post is about the pointlessness, most of the time, of "Works on X" comments and the comment is totally pointless.
